# Python find all regex string values

Tags: python

I would like to find all link titles (using bs4 to do scraping) contains strings: "news" OR "reporting" (the title contains either the two words should be the results)

I tried with:

```
search = re.compile(r"news")
search1 = re.compile(r"reporting")
for text in box.find_all("p",text= search or search1):
   #dosth
```

and

```
search = re.compile("news.+reporting")
for text in box.find_all("p",text= search or search1):
   #dosth
```

but these two codes only return matching with "news" but not with "reporting", so wondering how to do that? thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you share some of the data that you are working with? It will help us solve the problem for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look toward something like this

```
search = re.compile(r"reporting|news")
for text in box.find_all("p",text=search):
   #dosth
```

Note the `|` character, it acts as `or` inside the regex. The `|` can be used to `or` any arbitrary regex expressions and expression groups. Check the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) for more information.